# How to access Argument object inside arrow function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

The arguments Object inside `listOfArg` function refers to parent `arguments` with arrow function. And without arrow function `this` key reference would change and `listOfArg` function will no longer accessible through `this` change.

```
componentDidMount(){
      document.addEventListener('scroll', this.onScrollEvent);
  }

listOfArg = () => {
    console.log(arguments)
  }

onScrollEvent = (e) => {
     this.listOfArg("1", "2", "3", "4")
}
```

Comment: Please be more specific about what you want to achieve here

Comment: and what is your question exactly?

Comment: Well making `listOfArg` a normal function does not prevent the `onScrollEvent` arrow function from accessing its `this` value?!

Answer (score 0):

From [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

> An arrow function does not have its own this; the this value of the enclosing execution context is used.

If you use

```
listOfArg = () => {
    console.log(arguments)
}
```

`this` inside `onScrollEvent` would refer to the component `this` and you would get arguments passed to the component because arrow function would use enclosing execution context which is the React Component.

Now, if you do not use arrow function:

```
listOfArg() {
  console.log(arguments)
}
```

Here, `listOfArg` will have its own `this` and would print arguments it was called with: `["1", "2", ...]` which is expected.