# Can't get `arguments` of inner arrow function

Tags: javascript

I was making a decorator function in response to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48467463/how-do-i-return-the-number-of-times-a-function-is-invoked#48467589) when I realized it was not working as expected. The function simply counts how many times given function is called, and logs it.

```js
function countExecutions(fn) {
    let count = 0;
    return () => {
        console.log("called",++count);
        return fn.apply(this, arguments);;
    }
}

var test = countExecutions((a,b) => a+b);
var x = test(1,2);
console.log(x); // (a,b) => a+bundefined
```

I realized this is because `arguments`  refer to the arguments of the function `countExecutions` instead of my inner anonymous function. **So it logs `(a,b) => a+bundefined` instead of `3`.** Why can't I get arguments of inner anonymous function?

If I give it a name, it works as expected:

```js
function countExecutions(fn) {
    let count = 0;
    return function inner() {
        console.log("called",++count);
        return fn.apply(this, arguments);;
    }
}

var test = countExecutions((a,b) => a+b);
var x = test(1,2);
console.log(x); // 3
```

Comment: arrow functions don't have `this` and `arguments`

Comment: should also work without naming it - just doing a normal `function() {}`

Comment: Oh that's right!! So it's not about it being anonymous, just being arrow

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access Argument object inside arrow function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47068640/how-to-access-argument-object-inside-arrow-function)

Comment: @jhpratt: my question is close to that one, but I got more helpful answers. So I prefer not mark it as duplicate. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding arrow functions, here's your anonymous (not using the arrow function) version:

(Alternatively you can use arrow functions as noted in [@trincot's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48468182/2446254). )

```js
function countExecutions(fn) {
    let count = 0;
    return function(){
        console.log("called",++count);
        return fn.apply(this, arguments);;
    }
}

var test = countExecutions((a,b) => a+b);
var x = test(1,2);
console.log(x); // (a,b) => a+bundefined
```

Comment: Could you add @trincot 's alternative to complete your answer? Would be great for future similar questions.

Answer (score 2):

As stated, `arguments` is not defined for arrow functions. But why not use the spread syntax:

```js
function countExecutions(fn) {
    let count = 0;
    return (...args) => {
        console.log("called",++count);
        return fn.apply(this, args);
    }
}

var test = countExecutions((a,b) => a+b);
var x = test(1,2);
console.log(x); // 3
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't behave this way due to the function being named, but because you're using an arrow function. Arrow functions not only do not define their own function scope, but also no `arguments`:

> An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax than a function
>   expression and does not have its own this, arguments, super, or
>   new.target. These function expressions are best suited for non-method
>   functions, and they cannot be used as constructors.

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)